# How to add panel control from form1 to form2 in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I have two forms, Form1 and Form2. In Form2 I have a Panel1. But after added some control as per my requirement I removed it from Designer.cs, because i want add it from Form1.

I have a code where I can make Panel1 visible true. But i want add it, because its not present on Form2.

```
    private void lblUpdateNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Form2 f2 = new Form2() ((Panel)f2.Controls.Find("Panel1", true)[0]).Visible = true;
           f2.Show() ;
    }
```

Comment: What framework is this?

Answer (score 0):

So, just add Panel to Form2 using designer, make it invisible and turn it visible from Form1. Your requirements are not very clear.